# How to best organize my database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on a group chat Developed specifically for the collaboration of developers. I am currently transitioning the system from only containing one lobby (chat room) to allow each user to have their own unique lobby (with a lobby id).

I assign each user with the lobby id so that when they log in the correct messages load. In order to display the correct messages for a specific lobby, in the database, I assign each message with the unique lobby ID. This is what I have currently implemented.

However, I was wondering if it would be a smart idea to give each lobby its own table to put its messages in.

That way, one day instead of having 200,000 messages in one table, they could be distributed between many tables thus decreasing the query times.

Suggestions?

Comment: No, don't  do that. Don't generate tables depending on content.

Comment: you can have two tables one for inactive lobby and one for active lobbies. when a lobby is closed, its messages are flushed to inactive lobbies message. in this manner you can keep your table as smaller as possible.

Comment: As the other said: don't do that. Your DB will be a mess after a few months and you will roll back to your one-table for sure. [Key Partionning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-key.html) is probably a track to investigate if performance is your main concern. The key should obviously be your chat room_id  and in effect your queries on a specific chat room will execute (almost) as if they were in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, making a unique table for each chat room sounds like a pretty bad idea. It sounds like it will give you better performance, and it may be. BUT, it will make maintenance and future changes harder, makes your DB one big mess, and eventually, won't give you any benefit that can't be gained otherwise.

You should make a table for all the chat messages, with a "ChatID"/"LobbyID" column that makes the connection between the message and the relevant chat room.

Then, you should create secondary index on that column, or even use it as partitioning key. That way you can get a good performance, but without having a mess of tables.

Hope this helps.